# I have two Inner Join tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to show a workers all workers. This workers who fill the pull and the workers who does't fill pull. How could I do it by this query ?

```
SELECT  COUNT(CreatorEmail)  as 'Liczba wpisów w miesiącu',
        FORMAT([Created],'MM.yyyy') as 'Wpisy w poszczególnych miesiącach',nrski,CreatorEmail
      FROM [dbo].[Events]
       Inner Join PrzedhanShort ON Events.CreatorEmail=PrzedhanShort.email
      Group By FORMAT([Created],'MM.yyyy'),nrski,CreatorEmail
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: You have to use a left join !

Comment: I tried but i don't see a record with null values

Comment: Still i have see only 275 records, not the records with null

Comment: Develop good habits. One - regardless of language - is consistent coding style. You schema-qualify one table but not the other. You cram your code together making it difficult to read. You should define an alias for each table and use it when referencing any columns - that tells the reader which table contains which column. Lastly, we don't know your schema or goal. We don't know the source of "all values". That is a why a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is suggested.

Comment: Yes but I only want to show all records from table PrzedhanShort and if they haven't got values then shown 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be asking for `isnull`

Wrap the columns that are nullable in `isnull()` eg,

```
isnull(nrski,0) nrski, isnull(CreatorEmail,'') CreatorEmail
```

and

```
Group By FORMAT([Created],'MM.yyyy'), isnull(nrski,0), isnull(CreatorEmail,'')
```

Edit

Is this more in line with your expectations?

You are grouping rows which means you will only see distinct rows from the join, any duplicates will be removed by the grouping.

```
select  Count(CreatorEmail) over(partition by Format([Created],'MM.yyyy'))  as 'Liczba wpisów w miesiącu',
Format([Created],'MM.yyyy') as 'Wpisy w poszczególnych miesiącach', nrski, CreatorEmail
from PrzedhanShort p
left outer join [events] e on e.CreatorEmail=p.email
```

Comment: Yes but all time I have got only 257 records no more and I should Have if I read PrzedhanShort table 386. I dont see records wchich are Joined. I tried Inner Join Left and Right All times only 257 records shows.

Comment: I've done my best to understand what you mean, if you expect to see all rows including duplicates (I assume that's why you have fewer rows) you need to remove the grouping. I've edited above with another suggestion.

Comment: But in PrzedhanShort Table is more records There is 385 distinct records and the result don't show me any user with 0 writing so it not show me  more then one hundred person.

Comment: Use a `left outer` join to return all row regardless of matches

Comment: @GrzegorzZ Do you have any `where` condition on your actual query? If you have and it checks `events` table fields, then this may accidentally turn your `left join` into `inner` one.

Comment: Yes i Have got where statment. Left outer give me the same record as inner join.

Comment: I don't know why it don't work for all users